# Missing dependency in useEffect

Tags: reactjs

I know this has been asked a lot, I know I can disable it using the eslint override. I know that if you had defined the function inside the `useEffect` you'd wouldn't have this problem, and I know that if I had the func in the component I could wrap it in a `useCallback`.

But in my case, the dispatch comes from some Context.

So this is the code:

```
const { store, dispatch } = useContext(SomeContext);

useEffect(() => {
   const processed = processData(store.data);
   dispatch.setProcessedData(processed);
}, [store.data]);
```

If I add `dispatch` in the dependency array, it goes into a loop, I guess cause dispatch is destroyed and created in each re-render. Any way to fix it?

Comment: Can you destructure `setProcessedData` from dispatch?

Comment: Does dispatch _have_ to be destroyed and created in each re-render? You should probably fix it with e.g. `useCallback` in the context.

Comment: Is `dispatch` a function or an object? Typically it is used as a function but I see you're instead calling the `setProcessedData` method. You could try adding `dispatch.setProcessedData` in the dependency array instead of the whole object. If inside `SomeContext` that method is wrapped in a `useCallback` it shouldn't trigger re-renders.